# What's a word that means "make oneself feel stupid" or "make oneself appear stupid"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Almost like dumbing down, or under utilizing yourself?

Comment: Your title is asking two very different questions, no?

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for ***[self-deprecating](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/self-deprecating):***

> - tending to undervalue oneself and one's abilities.
> - belittling or undervaluing oneself; excessively modest.

The Free Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Undersell (as per dictionary.com):

> - to advertise with restraint
> - understate the merits of something.

If you say something like "Oh, I'm not that smart," you are probably **underselling** yourself.

You can also **humble** yourself.

Humble (as per dictionary.com):

> - to lower in condition, importance or dignity
> - abase

Comment: I think **humble** is the better of your two suggestions. I *feel* like the OP wants a word with "deliberate" connotations, and (in my opinion) **undersell** carries connotations of non-deliberateness. i.e. someone who undersells themself does so because they don't realise how good they are.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest [**put oneself down**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stop+putting+yourself+down&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=4&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstop%20putting%20yourself%20down%3B%2Cc0).

> put down (someone or something): to make someone or something appear foolish or unimportant. ([**Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+down))

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking for "make yourself **appear** stupid," or "make yourself **feel** stupid?" In the first case (giving the illusion of stupidity), there are some answers here already that I won't steal. In the second case (feeling embarrassed about your own stupidity), you could try ***"humiliation,"*** as in "he humiliated himself in front of the whole team."

However, speaking under correction, I don't think that there's a word that covers both meanings at the same time.

Comment: In a similar context to "humiliated", you could go with "embarrassed", as it relays a similar aura of shame

Answer (score 0):

What about "make a fool of yourself "?

Comment: This is supposed to be a single-word request.